# Captcha field not working on module in Yii2

Tags: module, yii2, captcha

I have a captcha field in an application form, that correctly works, and one in the `login` form of the `Users` **module**, that does not work.

In the `login` form I wrote:

```php
<?= $form->field($user, 'captcha')->widget(\yii\captcha\Captcha::className(), [
    'captchaAction' => 'user/captcha',  // Important, otherwise no image shown.
    'template' => '...',
]); ?>
```

In the `User` model I wrote:

```php
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    public $captcha;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ...
            /* Modified after the suggestion of Michal Hynčica. */
            /* I tried also 'users/user/captcha'. */
            ['captcha', 'captcha', 'captchaAction' => 'user/captcha'],
        ];
    }
```

In the `actions()` method of the `UserController` I wrote:

```php
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'captcha' => [
            'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
        ],
    ];
}
```

I also added this code in the `behaviors()` method, although in the other controller, where it works, I didn't write it:

```php
public function behaviors()
{
   return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['captcha'],
                    'allow' => true,
                ],
            ],
        ]
   ];
}
```

**Solved**. Having some scenarios in the `User` model, I had to add the "captcha" field to the `login` scenario:

```php
public function scenarios()
{
    return [
        ...
        self::SCENARIO_LOGIN => ['name', 'password', 'remember', 'captcha'],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using captcha with different captcha action than default `site/captcha` you have to set the [`$captchaAction`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-captcha-captchavalidator#$captchaAction-detail) property in validation rule too. So, in your user model:

```php
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    public $captcha;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // ...
            ['captcha','captcha', 'captchaAction' => 'users/user/captcha'],
        ];
    }
```

This is because the `yii\captcha\CaptchaAction` uses the action's unique ID as key when storing data in session. If the validation rule points to different captcha action it won't be able to validate the code properly.

Comment: Thank you, but it is still not working.

Comment: Then you will have to be more specific about your issue or provide [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Problem description "it's not working" is way too generic. I've tried this solution with the code you've provided in clean yii2 basic app project (with one exception: my user model extended `yii\base\Model` instead of `yii\db\ActiveRecord` and didn't implement IdentityInterface) and it worked fine.

Comment: Well, I modified the code above, inserting the code you suggested in your answer. Regarding your implementation, I think you did it in the application and not in a *module*. As I wrote at the beginning, in my application forms captcha fields work fine, in the Users *module* not.

Comment: I don't know what I could add as further information. I think that is all the needed code to understand the problem.

Comment: Maybe it might help to know, that I also tried to implement recaptacha3, and it also works in the application forms but not in the module ones.

Comment: No, I did it in module. Here is the whole app code https://github.com/hyncica/yii-captcha-in-module-poc, you can check code and test it yourself.

Comment: Ok, thanks, it works indeed, I have to figure out why mine does not. Thanks again.

Comment: @MichalHynčica Always best practice :) Appreciate