# Captcha field not validating on Yii2

Tags: validation, module, yii2, captcha, saving-data

I finally [succeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75848913/captcha-field-not-working-on-module-in-yii2) to get the captcha widget working in the `login` form of in a Yii2 `Users` module, but in the `register` form the `captcha` field only validates correctly, when calling `$user->validate()`, but not when calling `$user->save()`.

```php
if ($user->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $user->validate()) /* $user->validate() succeeds. */
{
    $user->hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($user->password);
    $user->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();

    if ($user->save()) /* $user->save() does not succeed. */
    {
```

The problem seems to be within the `validate()` method of the `Model` class, which returns `false`, after looping the `CaptchaValidator`:

```php
public function validate($attributeNames = null, $clearErrors = true)
{
    ...
    foreach ($this->getActiveValidators() as $validator) {
        $validator->validateAttributes($this, $attributeNames);
    }
    $this->afterValidate();

    return !$this->hasErrors(); /* Returns false. */
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are validating your model twice.
First time during the `$user->validate()` call in your `if` condition. The second time during the `$user->save()`.

When captcha is validated as valid, [the stored code is regenerated](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/5406e5dad3eaa4e9d58f65bb565d37adc4307f3b/framework/captcha/CaptchaAction.php#L195-L197).
That's why second validation of same code will fail.

Since your data are already validated there is no reason to validate them again during save. You can pass `false` as first argument to `save()` method to tell the model to skip validation.

```php
if ($user->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $user->validate())
{
    $user->hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($user->password);
    $user->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();

    if ($user->save(false))
    {
```

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks. I removed insted the first validation, it seems to work fine anyway.